# What is the format of Minecraft.net account names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

What is the format of [Minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net/) account names?

The information I have a use for is:

- what characters are permitted or prohibited?
- what is the maximum length?
- are they always treated as case-insensitive?

However, a **complete, exact** definition of the allowed format would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimum Length for Minecraft usernames?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179832/minimum-length-for-minecraft-usernames)

Comment: @Studoku Hm? This is an older, broader question. I just edited it a bit to expand its scope.

Comment: I will admit that that close vote was partly to prove a point and mostly to troll.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The username must be between 3 and 16 characters (inclusive).

The characters permitted are :

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_

Usernames are case-sensitive in games (above your head), but when logging in using the username, whether is it in caps or not, will still work.

Comment: Additional info: Logging in with a different username case does not change how you appear in-game.

Comment: The way Minecraft treats usernames is called [case-preserving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation) (though that term is usually only used when discussing filesystems).

Comment: Are spaces allowed?

Comment: @spudwaffle No.

Comment: Can the name start with a number?

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior Yes, it can.

Comment: Names must also be 3 characters or more. So between 3 and 16 characters, inclusive.

Comment: It may be useful to know that the minimum length requirement didn't exist at one point. [There are players who have less than three characters](https://namemc.com/profile/G).

Answer (score 6):

Trying to register with an illegal character gives an error and mentions the following as allowed:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_
```

And the longest username I could register was 'thisisalongusern'