# Minimum Length for Minecraft usernames?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Related to the question: ["What is the format of Minecraft.net account names?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/what-is-the-format-of-minecraft-net-account-names).

I was wondering if there is a minimum length for Minecraft usernames?

Comment: @kotekzot While the questions are similar, that one does not ask about minimum length.

Comment: @Batophobia not explicitly, but minimum length does fall under format - this question is a subset of the other question.

Comment: @kotekzot This question is off-topic because it could be considered similar to another question despite the fact that the accepted answer (nor any other answers) to that question don't answer or consider this one.</sarc>

Comment: I wrote the proposed duplicate. FWIW, I have now modified it to explicitly ask for complete information about the format, because that's the spirit of what I meant to ask even if I only gave a specific list of points originally.

Comment: @Studoku I didn't say it's off-topic, I said it's a duplicate, which it is. Spreading this information between 2 questions makes no sense.

Comment: This question should not be flaged as duplicated, since the related link is not asking or answering the same thisn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum is 4 characters as shown in the screen shots below.

This was changed from 3 to 4 but not sure when as mojang don't publish changes to account details in changelogs.

You will still see the old 3 digit usernames and the odd 2 digit ones. they are legit probably old accounts or developer exceptions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Jeb_ is four characters though.

Comment: @Arperum ok true but i have found out there is one two letter name but it belongs to notches wife so doesn't count

Comment: I have a reliable source (whose username is 3 letters) that once told me that while the minumum length *used to be* 3 letters (or less?), that no longer seems to be the case. The system would not let him register a new name that was also 3 letters.

Comment: How is the fact that Skythekidrs is longer then 3 relevant to minimum length of usernames? Of course longer usernames are allowed, the question is: is three the minimem, or is a username of 4 (or 5) characters required now? Ez doesn't count, because developers can and will cheat their own restrictions.

Comment: Edited with confirmation